# Have to login twice

Tags: login, 18.10

I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 everything went fine except this problem. When the computer locks  I have  to login twice.  I have to  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then login to my account again and then after I prompted again to login into  my  locked account again. otherwise I all see is the background and  application taskbar. Strange the locked user prompt has this strange background showing the stars of the universe which I never setup.

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer not to I was forced to reinstall the GNOME.

In order to install the full Ubuntu GNOME desktop use the tasksel command. In case the tasksel command is not available on your system you can install it by:

```
sudo apt install tasksel
```

Once the tasksel command is installed, begin the GNOME desktop installation by executing:

```
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

To start GNOME session on your  system console and execute:

```
sudo service gdm3 start
```